# Serilog does not write logs to file

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I have solution where are 5 .net-core projects, one - console application and rest are class library. In class Program in main function I have:

```
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.LiterateConsole()
            .WriteTo.Async(a => a.RollingFile("logs\\myapp-{Date}.txt",
                outputTemplate : "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level} {Type}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception} {SourceContext}"))
            .CreateLogger();

         Log.Information("Server starting ...");

            //Here I have class which invoke a lot of(6-7) Tasks 
                NewTask task = new NewTask();
                task.Start();
            //And I end my Main function with
         Log.CloseAndFlush();
         Console.ReadLine();
```

In my all classes when i catch exceptions I've written:

```
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.ForContext<ClassName>().Error(e, "Somethign went wrong");
        }
```

In new log I have only "Server starting..." nothing more. What I should to? While I debug I see that my program run lines with `catch`. Now I have no idea what to do. Maybe someone has similar problem?

**EDIT**
I modeled from here https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Getting-Started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only call `Log.CloseAndFlush()` after all of the tasks have completed. Placing it after the `Console.ReadLine()` call should demonstrate this.

Comment: Omg, thank you. I would never think about it. After RedLine, for me is insane because ReadLine stops the program. But somehow it works

Comment: Great, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Are you adding Serilog to your `LoggerFactory`?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
{
    loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
}
```

Comment: you know that we are talking about .net-core not asp?

Comment: good point, can you show a little bit more code? I just tried the Serilog example and it works fine.

Comment: I cannot :( But as you can see in my EDIT section I pasted example which works for me too, of course in simple solution with one project